# Hide Elements/Symbols Upon Loading In Certain Browser Sizes with JS? (Adobe Edge Animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, adobe-edge

**Note this is using Adobe Edge Animate.  I've tried media queries and pre-made HTML files, but to get what I'm looking for I need to have it as a Edge Stage.

So I have 2 menus as Symbols in my project 'mobileNav' and 'deskNav'.  My goal is to have either mobileNav load upon being <=800, and deskNav to load with >=800.

As of now, it loads both symbols until the browser is flexed.  Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOpN.jpg) via imgur.

My code for 'compositionReady' is:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 799) {
   //alert('Less than 799');
   sym.$("deskNav").css("visibility","hidden");
   sym.$("mobileNav").css("visibility","visible");
}
else {
   //alert('More than 799');
   sym.$("deskNav").css("visibility","visible");
   sym.$("mobileNav").css("visibility","hidden");
}
```

I'd like it to only load one or the other depending on the size of the browser (mobile and desktop)

Thanks a bunch ahead of time!

Comment: You should really look into responsive design... it's 99.9% CSS based and much quicker than throwing `jQuery` into the mix. Perhaps [Foundation?](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: It's an adobe edge animate issue. There is a way I found out actually. Adaptive stage divs from their commons a few years back.

Answer (score -1):

You can use media queries for hide/show the navigation options

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)  {
  .deskNav
   {
     display:none;
   }
  .mobileNav
   {
     display:block;
   }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px)  {
  .deskNav
   {
     display:block;
   }
  .mobileNav
   {
     display:none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### A) You're looking too deep into it:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="mobile">Hello world</p>
<p class="desktop">Hello world</p>
```

Define your webpages singularly with both elements to save time.

**Try resizing the window:** http://jsfiddle.net/3vXpR/1/

#### B) Media queries, not Javascript:

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 801px)  {
    .desktop {
        display: block;
    }
    .mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)  {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }    
}
.desktop {
    color:#CCC;
}
.mobile {
    color:#FCC;
}
```

**`CSS` can handle browser resizes *much* better than `jQuery` can.**

**Try resizing the window:** http://jsfiddle.net/3vXpR/1/

#### OR...

Just use a `framework` that does everything for you.

**Check out:**

- http://foundation.zurb.com/ *(Easy)*
- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ *(Hard)*

Comment: You can't call media queries in edge animate unfortunately.  I've already tried this.  I started out simple.  Now it's become complicated.  It's some really -interesting- software.  I also already have used responsive CSS, but my goal is to make a interactive/animated website using Edge.